# I want to plot the NAs of a dataframe using a simple command in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with about 111 columns and 37,000 rows. I have removed the columns that entirely have zeros and NAs and now I have 57 columns. Now the challenge is I still have NAs distributed in the dataset in many columns, I thought of trying to show the distributed NAs using a plot. While browsing github I came across the below command using the `Amelia` package. This seemed useful for producing a plot for smaller datasets however when I ran this command in my large dataset the system hangs and crashes. I think it is not efficient enough to plot NAs from a large dataset.

Is there an equivalent command, to the below, that is efficient and fast for plotting the NAs distributed in a large dataframe?

```
Amelia::missmap(matches, main = "Missing values")
```

Comment: check the VIM package. That might help.

Comment: I think any solution is going to be pretty difficult with 37,000 rows and 111 columns, not necessarily because of computational difficulties but simply because of a limited number of pixels on your screen/piece of paper.  If you have a big/high-res screen that's 5000 pixels wide and arrange your plot in portrait (so that rows are along the wide dimension), and you have a *single pixel per element*, your picture will be 5 screens wide ...

Comment: can you show us an example of `Amelia::missmap` so we can see what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ben Bolker,the code is in line no.61 in the following link https://github.com/hariharanwarm/PredictTheWorldCup/blob/master/src/WorldCup.R

Comment: I wanted you to paste e.g. some pictures like this: https://njtierney.github.io/r/missing%20data/rbloggers/2015/12/01/ggplot-missing-data/ into your actual question. We shouldn't have to go download a big file/run a bunch of code just to see what you want ...

Comment: @Ben,works for me, but it takes little longer to execute, thats probably due to the size..Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vis_miss` function from `naniar` package should help you visualize `NA`'s from your large dataset: 
http://naniar.njtierney.com/articles/naniar-visualisation.html

[image]

Comment: I get this error,                                                                              vis_miss(data_purified)
Error in vis_miss(data_purified) : 
  Data exceeds recommended size for visualisation, please consider
         downsampling your data, or set argument 'warn_large_data' to FALSE.

Comment: @hariharans Yeah, this is a known issue and for a detailed discussion about why this behavior was implemented, see this issue thread (https://github.com/ropensci/visdat/issues/54). 

At any rate, do `vis_miss(data_purified, warn_large_data = FALSE)` and it **might** work. Whether large datasets will be displayed or not depends on the capabilities of the machine you are working on.

Comment: Great,works for me, is there a way to add some colours, grey and black doesn't look attractive.By the way it takes some time to execute probably due to its size

Comment: @hariharans Sure, it returns `ggplot2` object, so you can use `ggplot2` functions to modify palettes. For example: `vis_miss(data_purified, warn_large_data = FALSE) + ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")`

Comment: How can I squeeze the plot a little so the last few variables are visible.at the moment the last few variables are not visible.

Comment: You mean they are not visible in the Rstudio default plot in the pane? What happens if you instead save the plot with `ggplot2::ggsave` with a suitable value for `height` and `width`? You can toy around with values of `width` until it produces the plot you like.